# Android Studio build fails with "java not found"

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a project with Gradle, but the build is failing with the error "java not found". Whilst this works absolutely fine on the command line, it fails in Android Studio. The exact error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRealDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --output /Users/amlcurran/Projects/Messages/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/real/debug/libGoogleAnalyticsServices-9d8e3e3fe0cc3007420cb25dbd38e357c5461aad.jar /Users/amlcurran/Projects/Messages/app/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar
>     Error Code:
>       127
>     Output:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx: line 89: exec: java: not found

My JDK Location (in Project Settings>SDK Locations) is set to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home", although every time I change this it seems to revert itself.

UPDATE: A non-Gradle project builds fine.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be an issue I introduced yesterday trying to get the non-Gradle project working.

I had set my JDK to the one specified above but had issues with compiling, so moved my java executable in `usr/bin/java`. This clearly messed up Gradle - moving it back made Gradle work again (although I assume it has now broken the non-Gradle project).

Comment: If you're using non-Gradle projects, you might want to consider switching to IntelliJ Community Edition (which has the same Android plugin as Android Studio and most of the same functionality). Android Studio tends to hide the IntelliJ SDKs that you need to configure to make non-Gradle projects work. One downside is that IJ CE ships with an older version of the Android plugin, and you can't update its plugin without hacking around in the installation.